# Button does not look the same on mobile as in android studio layout view

Tags: android, android-studio, button, view

I have defined three buttons using the same drawable background file "find_button.xml". The "start server activity" button (id="start_button") ignores for some reason the file "find_button.xml" .
I am not able to find any mistake..

Layout view in android studio:

[image: Layout view in android studio]

Layout View on mobile:

[image]

xml Layoutfile:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1A91C6"
    tools:context=".ServerInitial">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/find_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#DCB235"
        android:onClick="startServerActivity"
        android:text="@string/start_server_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/close_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/peers_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="?android:attr/colorMultiSelectHighlight"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/start_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/find_button">


    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/find_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#DCB235"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_72dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="sucheGeräte"
        android:text="@string/suchen_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/find_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#E3931D"
        android:onClick="closeConnection"
        android:text="@string/close_connection"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

drawable backgroundfile "find_button.xml"

```
    <?xml vers`enter code here`ion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

New Info: I installed new and realized , that while permission requests showed up, the button looked as it was supposed to look.After permission requests had been confirmed, the button changed back to it's old design.

[image]

I am using a pretty nice routine "has permissions" in onCreate for checking permissions, maybe the bug is somewhere there.

```
public class ServerInitial extends AppCompatActivity implements WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener, WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public WifiP2pManager manager;
public WifiP2pManager.Channel channel2;
public BroadcastReceiver receiver;
public IntentFilter intentFilter;
private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers_list = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView peerslist;
private int count = 0;
private String[] devicenames;
public WifiP2pDevice device;
public Button start;


private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {

        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
};

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS))
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);


    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);


    assert manager != null;
    channel2 = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    receiver = new P2PBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel2, ServerInitial.this, ServerInitial.this,
            ServerInitial.this);
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_initial);

    start = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    // Check if recreating a previously destroyed instance.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore value of members from saved state.
        devicenames = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("list");
        fillListe();
    } else {

        devicenames = null;

        // Initialize members with default values for a new instance.
        // ...
    }


    manager.discoverPeers(channel2, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            System.out.println("Da draussen ist was los .......");
            //ergebnisSuche.setText("Da ist was los...");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            System.out.println("Da draussen ist nix los .......");
            //ergebnisSuche.setText("Da ist nix los...");

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: to make sure there is no issues in your java/behavior; just remove any behavior code and leave `setContentView` .. also try it on different devices and see

Comment: removed everything, it works..

Comment: I also tried my app on Samsung S4, Samsung Tablet A6 and Samsung S10. On S10 it works without problems, on the other devices works only with removing all behaviour code

Comment: can you remove `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: removed, no difference...

Comment: Dear Zain, found a solution...(see my added answer) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in your code. Try reinstalling your app once and it should work fine. if it doesn't try invalidate caches and restart option in your android studio and then install/run your app. 
I tried your same code in my physical device as well as in emulator and here are the outputs. 
[Physical Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ONE.jpg)

[image: Emulator]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and t failed again. I installed new and realized , that while permission requests showed up, the button looked as it was supposed to look.After permission requests had been confirmed, the button changed back to it's old design.I have attached the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I apply some changes to the "start server" button later in my code. This seems to make the button to ignore the background drawable. 
I assigned in my code the drawable with "start.setBackground(...) and now it works. (see code below)

```
 @Override
public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {
    if (info.groupFormed) {

        if (info.isGroupOwner) {


            //Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ServerActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent1);
            start.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGreen));
            start.setText("Connected !! Push Button to start..");
            start.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.find_button));
            start.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            start.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            start.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
```